# react testing libray test components with side effects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react component called Home.In here I have a button called Refresh. I do want to write a unit test using react testing libray and jest to make sure the button rendered correctly.

This is my Home.tsx component

```
import { Button, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import CocktailCard from "../components/cocktail-card";
import axiosInstance from "../utils/axios";
import { Cocktail } from "../types/cocktail";
import RefreshIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Refresh";
export default function Home() {
  const [cocktails, setCocktails] = React.useState<Cocktail[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const loadCocktails = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const [random1, random2, random3, random4, random5] = await Promise.all([
        axiosInstance.get("random.php"),
        axiosInstance.get("random.php"),
        axiosInstance.get("random.php"),
        axiosInstance.get("random.php"),
        axiosInstance.get("random.php"),
      ]);
      const cocktailsList: Cocktail[] = [];
      random1.data.drinks.forEach((drink: Cocktail) =>
        cocktailsList.push(drink)
      );
      random2.data.drinks.forEach((drink: Cocktail) =>
        cocktailsList.push(drink)
      );
      random3.data.drinks.forEach((drink: Cocktail) =>
        cocktailsList.push(drink)
      );
      random4.data.drinks.forEach((drink: Cocktail) =>
        cocktailsList.push(drink)
      );
      random5.data.drinks.forEach((drink: Cocktail) =>
        cocktailsList.push(drink)
      );
      setCocktails(cocktailsList);
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadCocktails();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Grid
        item
        xs={12}
        sm={12}
        md={12}
        lg={12}
        xl={12}
        justifyContent="flex-end"
      >
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          onClick={loadCocktails}
          startIcon={<RefreshIcon />}
        >
          Refresh
        </Button>
      </Grid>

      {loading ? (
        <div data-testid="loading-msg">
          Please wait while we load the cocktails
        </div>
      ) : (
        cocktails.map((cocktail) => <CocktailCard {...cocktail} />)
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

This is my test file home.test.tsx

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Home from "./home";
// import { Cocktail } from "../types/cocktail";

jest.mock("../utils/axios", () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      data: {
        drinks: [
          {
            strDrinkThumb:
              "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/2x8thr1504816928.jpg",
            strCategory: "Ordinary Drink",
            strDrink: "Margarita",
            idDrink: "11007",
            showFavoriteBtn: false,
            isFavorite: false,
            showRemoveBtn: false,
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  ),
}));

describe("home", () => {
  test("renders refresh button", () => {
    render(<Home />);
    const refreshButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Refresh" });

    expect(refreshButton).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I am getting this error

> Warning: An update to Home inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
> When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped
> into act(...):

I searched about this and seems I need to wrap some code inside the act utility function.
I am not sure how to do so. Which parts to include and why.

I did this and seems not working

```
test("renders refresh button", () => {
    act(() => {
      render(<Home />);
    });
    const refreshButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /Refresh/i });

    expect(refreshButton).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

How do I fix this with react-testing-libray?

Answer (score 1):

> I searched about this and seems I need to wrap some code inside the act utility function. I am not sure how to do so. **Which parts to include and why**.

Your Home component is doing data fetching on mount:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  loadCocktails();
}, []);
```

Additionally, the `loadCocktails` function will call `setLoading` and `setCocktails` to update the UI state.

When writing unit tests you use the [`act`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act) utility to ensure all these state updates have been processed and applied to the DOM before you make any assertions.

You can wrap the rendering with `act` like this:

```js
test("renders refresh button", async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    render(<Home />);
  });
  const refreshButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /Refresh/i });

  expect(refreshButton).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

You can see a full example on the [Data Fetching](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#data-fetching) section of the Testing Recipes documentation.